# error when playing a wav sound on cubieboard with qt "using null output device, none available"

Tags: c++, qt, audio, null, playback

I use Qt Creator 3.3.1 Based on Qt 5.4.1. my program should work on a cubieboard that has an embeded linux. Now I want to play a sound on cubieboard, but I got bellow errors.

code:

```
QSound::play("/home/cubie/sound.wav");
```

errors:

> using null output device, none available
>   QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error
>   decoding source

Second error is when I want to test mp3 file. Actually I have problem with the first error. I test my speaker by executing below line in cubie's terminal and I got that it works. But I can't play a sound with my program. It worth noting that I test Qt on ubuntu 14.04 for playing wav sound and there was no error.

```
aplay Wave-sound.wav
```